# Django I am unable to load the view I want to with a different URL

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to create a new view which I can link to with a button on the index page. Clicking the button is changing the URL in the browser but is not changing the view.

I tried to send an httpresponse in the view instead of trying to render a new html file hoping that that was the problem.

Main urls

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('posts.urls')),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('posts/', include('posts.urls')),
    url('forms/',include('posts.urls'))

]
```

App urls

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
    url(r'^forms/$', views.theform, name = 'forms')
]
```

Views

```py
def theform(request):

    manystuff = ManyStuff.objects.all()[:10]

    context = {
        'manystuff': manystuff
    }
    return render(request,'posts/randomform.html',context)
```

I expect to click the button on the index and load randomform.html on the /forms url. All it does is change the url to forms and keeps the same view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman will add that right now but this is the button (i know there is nothing wrong with the button because it successfully changes url) <a style="display:block" class="center-align" href="/forms">Display Form</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only include the app URLconf once. Since in your case you want to delegate all the URLs to the included file, just include it with an empty URL (and note, you should not terminate the pattern):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

Comment: This worked but I didn't really understand why. Why isn't this a problem for my posts url but a problem for this one, and why is the empty ' '  (as I noticed removing it completely breaks it)

Comment: It *is* a problem for posts. You don't actually have any URL matching /posts/; previously that URL, just like /forms/, would have been routed to the index page.